# Selenium - how to switch focus to overlay

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have an overlay with terms opening up on top of the main window. This is what the scrollbars look like:

[image: Scrollbar]

The new window is not recognized as a new 'window' or tab so I cant switch to it normally, neither is it an iframe so driver.switchTo().frame(iframe); will not work either. This is what I've tried so far:

1) Clicking the element (By element I mean the overlay fragment containing the content. Does nothing.

2) Switching focus using the following:

```
jse.executeScript("var ov = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay__content'); window.setTimeout(function () { ov[0].focus(); }, 0); ");
```

3) Trying to click then use switch to active element:

```
_driver.getWebDriver().switchTo().activeElement();
```

None of these results work. I am trying to switch to a window then use ashot on it to get a full screen screnshot. This works very well with iframes but I'm confused as to how to proceed here. Any scrollBy(0,10) etc will result in the main window scrolling.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question.. would elaborate more???

Comment: In what way? An overlay opens the main window that I want to set focus on and then scroll, but I can't.

Comment: Could you share full view of screenshot instead of side view??

Comment: If it's just a plain html tag, why would you need to scroll in it? If you select it like any other element, you have all the information about it.

Comment: Is it a new browser window? Or just a div inside of the page

Comment: I need to scroll because I need to take a full screenshot of it. And no, I'm afraid I cant Saraubh.

Comment: It's a div within the page, as I said just below the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll inside of the overlay div you can make a method with JavaScriptExecuter like this;

```
public void scrollDownInsideOf(WebElement element, int pxForScrollDown) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];", element, pxForScrollDown);
}
```

element should be the inside div with the overlay

Comment: The problem is not as much scrolling within the element but enabling ashot (https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot) to do so by setting 'focus' to the element like you can do for iframes. But I'll give this a go and see how it pans out, thanks.

Comment: If It's just a div as you say, you cannot use switchTo() like you can do with windows to iframes. Because there is nothing to switch, it's a content of the page source.